# Error building meteor app with "node main.js"

Tags: meteor

When I run node `main.js` in  project meteor folder, this is what I get.

My `nodejs` version is `v0.11.15`.
My meteor version is `Meteor 1.3.4.4`.

> /home/getfeliz/iis/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
>                                                   throw(ex);
>                                                        ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at runWebAppServer (packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:589:19)
>       at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.webapp.webapp_server.js (packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:807:1)
>       at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
>       at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
>       at /home/getfeliz/iis/bundle/programs/server/packages/webapp.js:831:1
>       at /home/getfeliz/iis/bundle/programs/server/packages/webapp.js:844:3
>       at /home/getfeliz/iis/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:297:10
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/getfeliz/iis/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>       at /home/getfeliz/iis/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:133:5

Can you please help?
I have tried to uninstall and reinstall fibers and bcrypt, but with no success.

Comment: Are you getting an error if run with Meteor command?

Answer (score 1):

### Pre-requsites

1. Visual Studio 2012 (?) with C++
2. Python
3. demeteorizer(npm)
4. node and npm 32bit
5. Meteor for Windows
6. MongoDB

Step 1: 
    Inside meteor app run this 
       `demeteorizer -o c:/deploy/production` 
Step 2: 
    `cd /c/deploy/production/bundle
    cd programs/server
    npm install` 
Step 3: 
  `Fibers and Bcrypt can't compile
   Download fiber http://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-1.0.10.tgz
   Extract and copy in node_modules
   cd fibers
   node build` 
Step 4:   
   `change npm/babel-compiler package.json find fibers and change to /fibers-1.0.10 same with node_modules/meteor-promise packag.json find fibers` 
Step 5: 
   `Remove npm-bycrpt package from ..server\npm folder (delete manually)
    be sure  you have ms build + c++ compiler` 
Step 6: 
    `run “npm install bcrypt” from ..programs\server`